# In Dart, what's the difference between setting a `lambda` as part of a constructor or setting a normal class

Tags: dart, lambda, closures

I've seen this kind of stuff when constructing a class:

```dart
  class A {
    A(this.attr)

    final String Function() attr;
  }
```

```dart
  main() {
    final myStringAttr = 'some-string';

    final a = A(()=> myStringAttr);
  }
```

And the above works in the same way it works if my `A class` definition would be:

```dart
  class A {
    A(this.attr);

    final String attr;
  }
```

```dart
  main() {
    final myStringAttr = 'some-string';

    final a = A(myStringAttr);
  }
```

So, what's the difference? What does the constructor with the lambda different from a constructor without a lambda? Is the lambda less performant? When to use the lambda?

Comment: The first version requires that the callback be invoked every time `attr` is used.  That adds extra overhead, but it also allows `attr` to produce different values *dynamically*.  For example, the supplied callback could return different `String`s in different circumstances.  It's hard to know the intent without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

If the string were expensive to compute (e.g. it interpolates segments that are slow to compute, involves lots of processing to format things, etc.), then the lambda defers the evaluation of that string until it's actually needed.

This is pretty common for things like assertions (where they almost never are triggered, so the message is most frequently discarded), exception messages, etc.

For simple strings, the extra/allocation of the lambda would actually be marginally slower, but authors who use this are making the bet that it pays off because of the large saves for complex strings.